# Server returns 421 HTTP error when Fiddler is not running

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, fiddler

I'm building an API for Pixiv and so far I've managed to complete the login process and searching by tags works as well.

Now I want to **download** the image on the selected webpage. At first I was getting some certificate errors. I fixed that by temporarily ignoring certificate validation.

Then a very interesting thing happened... If Fiddler was running in the background - the response was successfully received and I was able to download the image. No problems, whatsoever.

But when the Fiddler was NOT running, the **remote server returned the 421 error code**.

Things I've already tried:

- Closing every response manually AND using the "using" statement
- Enforced the Keep-Alive header.
- Explicitly declared the use of HTTP/1.1
- Changing proxy settings on the HttpWebRequest object

---

My image request code looks like this:

```
HttpWebRequest imagerequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imgLink);
imagerequest.Host = $"i.pximg.net";
imagerequest.UserAgent = USER_AGENT;
imagerequest.Accept = "image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8";
imagerequest.Referer = post.PostLink;
imagerequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch, br");
imagerequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,sl;q=0.6");

byte[] imagecontent;
using (var imageresponse = (HttpWebResponse)imagerequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (var imagestream = imageresponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        imagecontent = imagestream.ReadStream();
    }
}
```

(I also send a request before this one in order to get the image link)

Example of "imgLink":

> https://i3.pixiv.net/img-original/img/2014/02/09/00/10/03/41485846_p0.jpg

Fiddler displays the sent request as this:

```
GET https://i.pximg.net/img-original/img/2014/02/09/00/10/03/41485846_p0.jpg   HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,   like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
Accept: image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://www.pixiv.net/whitecube/user/2824699/illust/41485846
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,sl;q=0.6
Host: i.pximg.net
```

Fiddler does not show any signs of HTTP protocol violations.

Comment: Does Fiddler show any "HTTP Protocol Violation" warnings when it is running your app's traffic? What is an example value of the `imgLink` variable-- does it specify the same `i.pximg.net` hostname?

Comment: Edited the question. Added an example of "imgLink" and what the Fiddler shows. The "3" in "imgLink" seems to disappear when looking at the Fiddler's request Raw data

Comment: If you correct the `.Host` value to the correct value (`i3.pixiv.net`) does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I was just blind. The "*imgLink*" had the **wrong hostname** set the entire time, but I didn't notice it because the hostnames were so similar. I guess Fiddler was automatically fixing that for me...

Next time I will be sure to triple-check the hostname. Thanks for for all the help.

Comment: Yeah, Fiddler *should* be showing a "HTTP Protocol Violation" each time that it fixes it up; if you don't have Fiddler configured to show violations, you should enable at least `Warn on critical errors` inside Tools > Fiddler Options > General > Protocol Violations.

Comment: I had that already set, but got no warnings. Maybe I should set it to `Warn on all errors` instead?